# How to create a test store to work with the API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to work with the **API** to make a proof of concept.  **The older version** so Magento used to have a **test store** that could be made for free and run for 30 days. Is there something similar for Magento 2?  I want to work out all the major pieces prior to going back to the client and I would like to be able to do it for cheap or free.

Ideally it would have few products that I could fake orders and fake order updates.   I could try the different ways of authentication to see which works best for my system.  Basically go through the big pieces so I can get a real estimate on what needs to get done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a local Magento 2 and install the sample data module. That should solve your issue. If you don't want to set up a web server, PHP and DB locally, you might be interested in the Magento 2 Dev Box.

All information I mentioned can be found in the [Magento 2 DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/)